# error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: Bad magic when installing an rpm

Tags: cmake, redhat, rpm

I packaged an rpm using

```
  make package
```

command, and copied the resulting rpm to another machine which has a company specific OS. Now when I try to install the rpm using

```
  rpm --nodeps -i filename.rpm
```

I get the error the same as the one in the title.

So I ran

```
  rpm -qa | grep rpm
```

on the machine used to build the rpm package, and got this:

```
  rpm-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64
  rpm-devel-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64
  rpm-python-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64
  rpm-libs-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64
  rpm-build-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64
  redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-51.el6.noarch
```

After a bit of investigation, I tried removing the redhat-rpm-config package and bam, rpm installation worked on the other machine. Now, this is a solution and all but I don't think I can just uninstall this package for every machine that we're going to use in creating the rpm. Is there any other way to ignore this redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-51.el6.noarch when creating an rpm package using cmake?

Comment: Show us how `make package` creates a `filename.rpm` ?

Answer (score 2):

What is the RPM version of the system you are installing on?  Are its sources publicly available somewhere?

There could be various compatibility issues if you build binary RPMs using a newer RPM/distribution.  In general, we build binary RPMs using the RPM and `redhat-rpm-config` versions  in the buildroot (which is created by mock) itself, which matches the target RPM version, even if the build host has a newer RPM version.

If this is not an option for you, I would look at specific RPM features controlled by `redhat-rpm-config`.  The one that sticks out to me immediately is payload compression:

```
# Use XZ compression for binary payloads
%_binary_payload w2.xzdio
```

Other changes include support for larger files, but this does not seem to be the issue here because it would not change by uninstalling the `redhat-rpm-config` package.

Comment: hi. The machine used to build the rpm has rpm version 4.8.0, and the machine I'm trying to install it in has rpm version 5.1.9 :)

Comment: Sorry, the interesting information is the RPM version on the target (and its provenance).

Comment: I edited my comment above. The target machine has newer rpm version

Answer (score 0):

You very likely made binary RPM using rpmbuild on different OS than was the target OS. You should use "mock" for building the package.

```
dnf install mock
mock -r epel-6-x86_64 yourpackage.src.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve "error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: Bad magic" issue at RPM package installation on your machine:

1/ List rpm pkgs which are installed on the server machine (the machine on which the rpm pkg is generated):
   $ rpm -qa | grep rpm
                 ….
                 ….
2/ If pkg redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-51.el6.noarch is present in the given list,  desinstall it:

```
$ rpm -e redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-51.el6.noarch
```

3/ Generate now the pkg and tranfer it on your dev machine. Pkg installation should work.

```
 Philippe.
```